# Rails radio buttons - one choice for multiple columns in on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want user to choose one option out of three for one model.

I.e.  I have a model Video, that can be rated as positive/negative/unknown

Currently I have three columns with boolean values (pos/neg/unknown).

Is it the best way to handle this situation?

What should the form look like for this?

Currently I have something like

```
<%= radio_button_tag :positive, @word.positive, false %> 
<%= label_tag :positive, 'Positive' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :negative, @word.negative, false %> 
<%= label_tag :negative, 'Positive' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :unknown, @word.unknown, false %> 
<%= label_tag :unknown, 'Positive' %>
```

But obviously it allows multiple selections, while I am trying to restrict it to just one..

What to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If would go with a string column let's say `rating`.

then in your form:

```
# ...
<%= f.radio_button :rating, 'unknown', checked: true %>
<%= f.radio_button :rating, 'positive' %>
<%= f.radio_button :rating, 'negative' %>
# ...
```

It only allows one selection

**edit** The exact same but using radio_button_tag:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'rating', 'unknown', true %>
<%= radio_button_tag 'rating', 'positive' %>
<%= radio_button_tag 'rating', 'negative' %>
```

Comment: I did exactly that (changed the column for string) and put that form in and I get this error: undefined method `positive?' for #<Word:0x007fb9962fa830>

Answer (score 1):

I think you need smth like this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag :rating, 'positive', @word.rating == :positive %> 
<%= label_tag :positive, 'Positive' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :rating, 'negative', @word.rating == :negative %> 
<%= label_tag :negative, 'Positive' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :rating, 'unknown', @word.rating == :unknown %> 
<%= label_tag :unknown, 'Positive' %>
```

Here all radio buttons will have the same `name` attribute (that is `'rating'`) but will have different `value` attribute (`'positive', 'negative' and 'unknown'` respectively). In the last parameter you pass `true` or `false` to mark one of them as selected.